# Comparison of almost planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, terminology, planar-graphs

I have multiple graphs all of which are almost planar. Is there any existing terminology / method which compares them, such that one can say which one is more planar? This could simply be the required number of edge removal to make a graph planar.

All I want to know if there is a standard in the community.

Comment: It appears the term "crossing minimization" is used to measure how close a graph is to planar, but that long research has shown to be [a difficult problem in practice](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~hlineny/papers/credge-gd06.pp.pdf).

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see your comment. Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Crossing number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_%28graph_theory%29).

For cubic graphs, the smallest graphs requiring 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 crossings are K33, Petersen, Heawood,  Möbius-Kantor,  Pappus, and Desargues (A fact I established with Geoff Exoo).

[Genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29)

K7 can be embedded on a torus, so it's a genus 1 graph.

Comment: Both computations are NP-hard, but (in your experience) is one measure easier in practice to obtain?

Comment: Crossing number is currently easier to calculate, because the program is written.  I don't know of an existing "is this graph toroidal?" checker, but I'd love to run it on a bunch of graphs if someone has it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found it. On the Crossing Number of Almost Planar Graphs.

Answer (score 0):

**[Graph skewness](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphSkewness.html)** is another measure of how planar graph a graph is. It follows the definition that you suggested: the minimal number of edges that have to be removed to make the graph planar.